# I have decrypted ecryptfs encrypted /home, now what?

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, ecryptfs

Long story short:

Currently I have a `/home` partition (with no os installed, no root partition) encrypted with `ecryptfs`. Following numerous tutorials and guides, I have successfully mounted the decrypted folder from a Live `Ubuntu 18.04` USB at `/tmp/ecryptfs.5vNHafiU`. **I can see all my files and have access to them perfectly fine.**
However, I have no idea what to do now. All the tutorials stops at this point.

I would like to **replace the encrypted /home partition with the decrypted data.**

After that, I plan to install Ubuntu using that `/home` partition. Apparently the data will be preserved as long as I uncheck the 'format' box for the partition. I don't think I can do it when it's still encrypted, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How much data do you have on this partition? Can you copy it off to a usb drive? If so copy it off, do your Ubuntu install and copy the data back. Alternatively can you make enough space on your existing drive for a new partition and copy it there?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem quite quickly after I posted. Sorry for not posting this immediately.

**What I did:**

I had about 300 Gb of data on a 1Tb drive. So I created another partition large enough to hold the data, mounted it and copied everything to the new partition using the cp command.

`cp -R /tmp/ecryptfs.5vNHafiU /NEW_PARTITION/MOUNTPOINT`  the extention of the ecryptfs folder will be different for yours.

At this point I could've used the standard ubuntu live usb install method, however I came across a bug report post saying that it would fail, where the op's system was, very similar to mine, completely destroyed(bit of an exaggeration).

Instead, I ran the **ubuntu boot repair**. To be frank I am not sure what it did, I'm certain that it reinstalled GRUB, but apparently it reinstalled ubuntu as well since that's what happened.

P.S I noticed that PonJar also commented this method, I much appreciate that.

Comment: By the way, I feel the need to comment on the extraordinarily long time that the copying took. Normally moving that partition using `gparted` would take about 2 hours, whereas this took more than 6 hours. I'm not sure why.